# Create a dictionary containing lambda functions to access the attributes of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two classes, respectively Person and Model (below), I need to create a dictionary (self.reporter) that contains the attributes of the person class as follows `key: attribute name`, `value: lambda function that returns the attribute of that object`.
At the moment my code works this way (below). The problem is that if I have 100 attributes to put in the dictionary (self.reporter) I have to do it by hand. How can I automate the creation of this dictionary?

EDIT: Why do I need the dictionary to be designed in this way?
Because I would like to use it with the [DataCollector module](https://github.com/projectmesa/mesa/blob/master/mesa/datacollection.py) of the mesa package that requires exactly this structure.

```py
import random

class Person():
    def __init__(self):
        self.age = random.randint(1,99)
        self.gender = random.choice(["male","female"])
        self.afraid_of_horror_movies = random.choice([True, False])


class Model():
    def __init__(self):
        self.population = list()
        for i in range(10):
            person = Person()
            self.population.append(person)

        self.reporter = { "age" : lambda x: x.age,
                          "gender": lambda x: x.gender,
                          "afraid_of_horror_movies": lambda x: x.afraid_of_horror_movies
                          }

model = Model()
print(model.reporter)
```

Comment: why do you need it in the first place? that looks like an antipattern

Comment: On a side note - it seems odd to be using `random.choices(["male","female"])[0]` here if you're only after a single result... could just do `random.choice(['male', 'female'])` instead...

Comment: @Francesco but what I'm saying is that `random.choice` (no s) is much better for a single item... and is equivalent of your `random.choices(...)[0]`...

Comment: I'm also confused about what you're trying to achieve here... how do you actually use `reporter` for instance... it'd help if you could provide a use-case as has been mentioned, this does seem somewhat an antipattern

Comment: @JonClements great, thanks, I didn't notice! I need this structure because I would like to use it with the DataCollector module of the mesa library. https://github.com/projectmesa/mesa/blob/master/mesa/datacollection.py

Comment: I'm not familiar with that but it does looks like you might be overcomplicating this if you only really want to expose attributes without computing things... can you make an [edit] to your Q to add a bit in about why you're using this (what you've mentioned  in comments here but if you can with a bit more detail) so it's clearer to others? (and the information is in the question and not in comments) - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't join the discussion in the comments, but if that's really the thing you need to do, I'd suggest a combination of `getattr` and `__dict__`:

```
def get_reporter(person):
    return {key: lambda x: getattr(x, key) for key in person.__dict__.keys()}
```

The only catch here is that you need an already-instantiated `Person` object in order to create a `reporter` for that object. I'm not sure there's a way around this, unfortunately, since Python dynamically creates instance variables, so you can only know about the ones that exist at the time of dictionary creation. You could use a dummy `Person` object that's hidden and just has `None` for all of its attributes, and then you could use that to create reporters.

It should also be noted that [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) will only contain writeable instance attributes.